# Anylogic - forklifts being stuck when loading storage

Tags: anylogic

I am using forklifts (free-space navigation type) to load pallets into storage. The storage has 1 rack, 5 bays, and 4 cells deep in each bay. It is of the stand-alone type. At some stage two forklifts will get stuck as shown in the image below.

I don't believe this is coding issue but more to do with the Anylogic collision behaviour. I have tried varying the 'Min distance to obstacle' value from 0m to 3m. I have also tried setting the size of the forklift as well as leaving that unchecked.

Does anyone have any tips on stopping this from happening? Please let me know if more information is required.

Thanks

[image]

Forklift Fleet settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict-resolution setup that you can use to solve those (inevitable) gridlocks. Use the "TransporterControl" element and play with it:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin. However, looking at the help, it appears that the controls are for path guided vehicles only. My forklifts are free roaming. Will the controls still work? If not, will I need to change them to path-guided?

Comment: Suggest you test it yourself :)